# find specific index position in string in php?

Tags: php

can someone help me  finding the position of the in string?

```
$data="e0ab71ab9ed24e627a24e7d65367936393cb3b39db9a9e84d65cd7a9254a4665";
```

here data contain length 64.

just I need if string  index position is 30 break the line and print next line remaining numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [`chunk_split()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chunk-split.php):

```
$data = "e0ab71ab9ed24e627a24e7d65367936393cb3b39db9a9e84d65cd7a9254a4665";
echo chunk_split($data, 30, "<br />");
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `substr()`.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php

```
echo substr($data, 0, 30), "\n", substr($data, 30);
```

Comment: Just curious, but do you use the commas to concatenate strings because it's supposedly faster (http://www.phpbench.com/) or just because it's a personal preference?

Comment: @PhpMyCoder, I use them because they are technically faster, even though it makes no noticeable difference at all.  I just figure, since it takes the same amount of time to type a comma as it does a period, it can't hurt to use them.

Comment: I've been considering switching to commas and you seem to make a pretty good argument for them. I think I'll make the switch. Thanks!